# Fitting a 2D Gaussian function using scipy.optimize.curve_fit - ValueError and minpack.error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-fitting

I intend to fit a 2D Gaussian function to images showing a laser beam to get its parameters like `FWHM` and position. So far I tried to understand how to define a 2D Gaussian function in Python and how to pass x and y variables to it.

I've written a little script which defines that function, plots it, adds some noise to it and then tries to fit it using `curve_fit`. Everything seems to work except the last step in which I try to fit my model function to the noisy data. Here is my code:

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt


#define model function and pass independant variables x and y as a list
def twoD_Gaussian((x,y), amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, offset):
    xo = float(xo)
    yo = float(yo)    
    a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
    c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    return offset + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo) + c*((y-yo)**2)))

# Create x and y indices
x = np.linspace(0, 200, 201)
y = np.linspace(0, 200, 201)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

#create data
data = twoD_Gaussian((x, y), 3, 100, 100, 20, 40, 0, 10)

# plot twoD_Gaussian data generated above
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data)
plt.colorbar()

# add some noise to the data and try to fit the data generated beforehand
initial_guess = (3,100,100,20,40,0,10)

data_noisy = data + 0.2*np.random.normal(size=len(x))

popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, (x,y), data_noisy, p0 = initial_guess)
```

Here is the error message I get when running the script using `winpython 64-bit` `Python 2.7`:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "E:/Work Computer/Software/Python/Fitting scripts/2D Gaussian function fit/2D_Gaussian_LevMarq_v2.py", line 39, in <module>
    popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, (x,y), data_noisy, p0 = initial_guess)
  File "C:\Python\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 533, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
  File "C:\Python\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 378, in leastsq
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

What is it that am I doing wrong? Is it how I pass the independent variables to the model `function/curve_fit`?

Comment: Since a gaussian is fully specified by its mean and covariance matrix, you actually don't need `curve_fit` at all. Here's one implementation: http://code.google.com/p/agpy/source/browse/trunk/agpy/gaussfitter.py

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The output of `twoD_Gaussian` needs to be 1D. What you can do is add a `.ravel()` onto the end of the last line, like this:

```
def twoD_Gaussian(xy, amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, offset):
    x, y = xy
    xo = float(xo)
    yo = float(yo)    
    a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
    c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    g = offset + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo) 
                            + c*((y-yo)**2)))
    return g.ravel()
```

You'll obviously need to reshape the output for plotting, e.g:

```
# Create x and y indices
x = np.linspace(0, 200, 201)
y = np.linspace(0, 200, 201)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

#create data
data = twoD_Gaussian((x, y), 3, 100, 100, 20, 40, 0, 10)

# plot twoD_Gaussian data generated above
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data.reshape(201, 201))
plt.colorbar()
```

Do the fitting as before:

```
# add some noise to the data and try to fit the data generated beforehand
initial_guess = (3,100,100,20,40,0,10)

data_noisy = data + 0.2*np.random.normal(size=data.shape)

popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, (x, y), data_noisy, p0=initial_guess)
```

And plot the results:

```
data_fitted = twoD_Gaussian((x, y), *popt)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
#ax.hold(True) For older versions. This has now been deprecated and later removed
ax.imshow(data_noisy.reshape(201, 201), cmap=plt.cm.jet, origin='lower',
    extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()))
ax.contour(x, y, data_fitted.reshape(201, 201), 8, colors='w')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that works! Interestingly the approach to actually fit the data to the Gaussian model works faster than: code.google.com/p/agpy/source/browse/trunk/agpy/gaussfitter.py as proposed by Zhenya. Its actually what I tried first. Now that the fitting routine works it's easy now to expand it to other functions.

Comment: While the code above indeed provides correct output parameters, for non-zero theta values the results will display incorrectly (the contours will look off) unless `origin='lower'` is added to the imshow command.  This is because contour and imshow have different default coordinate systems.

Comment: @Mike quite right - I didn't happen spot that because of the OP's particular choice of example params. I'll add the extra flag to my example.

Comment: @Kokomoking well yes, it certainly will converge faster if you initialize with the exact correct parameters :^)

Comment: def twoD_Gaussian seem to have a SyntaxError

Comment: @ali_m, to fit other shapes of 2d gaussians, I guess the `initial_guess`es might need to be changed right? However, to do this, I am not sure what each parameter does. If the equation underlying `twoD_Gaussian` or simply any external reference for additinal detailed information could be mentioned, that would be very helpful. 
Btw, for this shape of 2d gaussian, the answer works very well. With python 3.7 and matplotlib v3.3.2, I had to make few corrections though. I removed `ax.hold(True)` line (because of No attribute error) and made adjustments according to one of the answers below.

Answer (score 17):

To expand on Dietrich's answer a bit, I got the following error when running the suggested solution with Python 3.4 (on Ubuntu 14.04):

```
def twoD_Gaussian((x, y), amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, offset):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Running `2to3` suggested the following simple fix:

```
def twoD_Gaussian(xdata_tuple, amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, offset):
    (x, y) = xdata_tuple                                                        
    xo = float(xo)                                                              
    yo = float(yo)                                                              
    a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)   
    b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)    
    c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)   
    g = offset + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo)         
                        + c*((y-yo)**2)))                                   
    return g.ravel()
```

The reason for this is that automatic tuple unpacking when it is passed to a function as a parameter has been removed as of Python 3. For more information see here: [PEP 3113](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Answer (score 5):

`curve_fit()` wants to the dimension of `xdata` to be `(2,n*m)` and not `(2,n,m)`. `ydata` should have shape `(n*m)` not `(n,m)` respectively. So you use `ravel()` to flatten your 2D arrays:

```
xdata = np.vstack((xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()))
ydata = data_noisy.ravel()
popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, xdata, ydata, p0=initial_guess)
```

By the way: I'm not sure if the parametrization with the trigonometric terms is the best one. E.g., taking the one described [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) might be a bit more robust under numerical aspects and large deviations.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement ali_m's answer, here's the code snippet to fit a 2D Gaussian to an image, rather than fake data.

Example input image :

[image]

```
def twoD_Gaussian(xy, amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, offset):
    x, y = xy
    xo = float(xo)
    yo = float(yo)
    a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
    c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    g = offset + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo)
                            + c*((y-yo)**2)))
    return g.ravel()

# use your favorite image processing library to load an image
im = cv2.imread(r"path_to_load\im.png", -1) 
h, w = im.shape
data = im.ravel()

x = np.linspace(0, w, w)
y = np.linspace(0, h, h)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# initial guess of parameters
initial_guess = (1200, 120, 80, 20, 20, 0, 50)

# find the optimal Gaussian parameters
popt, pcov = curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, (x, y), data, p0=initial_guess) 

# create new data with these parameters
data_fitted = twoD_Gaussian((x, y), *popt)

cv2.imwrite(r"path_to_save\data_fitted.png", data_fitted.reshape(h,w))
```