# Fiting a sum of 2D gaussians to 2d data in python?

Tags: python, scipy

I have some 2D data, specifically scanned X-ray films. These have measurements of overlapping point source exposures. Example of data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oawlU.png

I want to find the peak positions, by fitting a sum of 2D gaussians to the data. I've tried several other methods with some success, including a "star search" method that locates the global maximum, fits a Gaussian and subtracts it. Looping this finds all of the peaks reasonably well, but it's unstable and not very accurate. I would like to use the star search output as a first guess for a fit, but I'm having trouble, implementing `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

I've made a function `twoD_envelope` that creates the 2D envelope of all the Gaussians found from the star search. This produces this output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KnpG.png

I was under the impression that I could use this to as an initial guess in `curve_fit`, however I get the following `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: twoD_envelope() takes 4 positional arguments but 358802 were given
```

358802 is 1 more than size of the data, which is a huge clue, but I can't work out what the problem is! I'm a physicist with "pragmatic" coding knowledge, so any input is very much appreciated.

The code is below.

```
def twoD_envelope(npoints, xls, yls, pars):

    envl = copy.copy(sq_image)
    envl[:] = 0


    for n in range(0,npoints):
        height, cx, cy, width_x, width_y = pars[n]
        FWHM = 0.5*(width_x+width_y)
        g=makeGaussian(shape(sq_image)[0],fwhm=FWHM,center=[cx+xls[n],cy+yls[n]])
        envl = envl + g

    return envl.ravel()

# Create x and y indices
x = np.linspace(0, np.size(sq_image[0]), np.size(sq_image[0])+1)
y = np.linspace(0, np.size(sq_image[1]), np.size(sq_image[1])+1)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
coords = [x,y]

data = sq_image

initial_guess = twoD_envelope(9,xls,yls,pars)

pars_opt, pars_cov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_envelope, coords, data, p0=initial_guess)
```

(`sq_image` is the data, an `ndarray` with shape `(599,599)`)

(`pars, xls, yxl` = lists of Gaussian fit parameters from star search)

(`makeGaussian` is a function defined elsewhere)

Answer (score 1):

I think your error message is a result of the function you pass to `curve_fit` which doesn't look like it is of the correct form. This may result in the `data` array interpreted as `vars` which results in the `TypeError` you see (difficult to tell without being able to run the code). According to the documentation, the function passed to curve_fit should,

> take the independent variable as the first argument and the parameters to fit as separate remaining arguments.

You may also need to use a star before initial_guess to pass it as a tuple, e.g.

`pars_opt, pars_cov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_envelope, coords, data, p0=*initial_guess)`

To fit a single 2D Gaussian, where p0 will be about 7 parameters, there is a very good answer which may help: [Fitting a 2D Gaussian function using scipy.optimize.curve_fit - ValueError and minpack.error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566379/fitting-a-2d-gaussian-function-using-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-valueerror-and-m).

A possible solution to your problem may be to loop through your 2D sq_image and use a single 2D Gaussian fit locally with the initial parameters for each from the star search...

EDIT: Code to fit Gaussian.

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import Image


def twoD_Gaussian((x, y), amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta):
    xo = float(xo)
    yo = float(yo)    
    a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
    c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    g = amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo) 
                            + c*((y-yo)**2)))
    return g.ravel()


# Create x and y indices
I = Image.open('./30155885.png')
p = np.asarray(I).astype('float')
w,h = I.size
x, y = np.mgrid[0:h, 0:w]

#Use only one channel of image
p = p[:,:,0]

#Fit 2D Gaussian
initial_guess = (3,10,10,20,40,0)
popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, (x, y), p.ravel(), p0=initial_guess)
data_fitted = twoD_Gaussian((x, y), *popt)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
cb = ax.imshow(p, cmap=plt.cm.jet, origin='bottom',
    extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()))
ax.contour(x, y, data_fitted.reshape(x.shape[0], y.shape[1]), 8, colors='w')


plt.colorbar(cb)
plt.show()
```

where image 30155885 is,

[image]

Note that only one channel of the image data is used (you should replace the data array with the one from sq_image). This results in,

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ed, that helps a lot. I'll have to rethink the code, but I'm afraid I don't understand your point about having too many variables. The 358802 number is sq_image.ravel(). If curve_fit can't handle that then it can't fit a single gaussian either? The number of parameters should be the 4 gaussian parameters of each peak, i.e. 36 total variables for 9 peaks. I like your suggestion of iteratively fitting single peaks, however I thought that's what curve_fit was trying?

Comment: Yeah, sorry late night so I was a little confused by the fitting problem and the number in your error (I though you planned to fit a sum of Gaussians with similar numbers of coefficients to points). I've edited my answer to show a fit to a single 2D Gaussian. You could then try to refine this to a sum of Gaussian, etc.