# Determening begin parameters 2D gaussian fit

Tags: python-3.x, scipy-optimize

I'm working on some code which needs to be able to preform a 2d gaussian fitting. I mostly based my code on following question: [Fitting a 2D Gaussian function using scipy.optimize.curve_fit - ValueError and minpack.error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566379/fitting-a-2d-gaussian-function-using-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-valueerror-and-m) . Now is problem that I don't really have an initial guess about the different parameters that need to be used.

I've tried this:

```
def twoD_Gaussian(x_data_tuple, amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, offset):
    (x,y) = x_data_tuple
    xo = float(xo)
    yo = float(yo)    
    a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
    c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    g = offset + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo) 
                            + c*((y-yo)**2)))
    return g.ravel()
```

The data.reshape(201,201) is just something I took from the aformentioned question.

```
mean_gauss_x = sum(x * data.reshape(201,201)) / sum(data.reshape(201,201))
sigma_gauss_x = np.sqrt(sum(data.reshape(201,201) * (x - mean_gauss_x)**2) / sum(data.reshape(201,201)))

mean_gauss_y = sum(y * data.reshape(201,201)) / sum(data.reshape(201,201))
sigma_gauss_y = np.sqrt(sum(data.reshape(201,201) * (y - mean_gauss_y)**2) / sum(data.reshape(201,201)))


initial_guess = (np.max(data), mean_gauss_x, mean_gauss_y, sigma_gauss_x, sigma_gauss_y,0,10)


popt, pcov = curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, (x, y), data, p0=initial_guess)

data_fitted = twoD_Gaussian((x, y), *popt)
```

If I try this, I get following error message: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Is the reasoning about the begin parameters correct?
And why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use the runnable code from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566379/fitting-a-2d-gaussian-function-using-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-valueerror-and-m) and substitute your definition of `initial_guess`:

```
mean_gauss_x = sum(x * data.reshape(201,201)) / sum(data.reshape(201,201))
sigma_gauss_x = np.sqrt(sum(data.reshape(201,201) * (x - mean_gauss_x)**2) / sum(data.reshape(201,201)))

mean_gauss_y = sum(y * data.reshape(201,201)) / sum(data.reshape(201,201))
sigma_gauss_y = np.sqrt(sum(data.reshape(201,201) * (y - mean_gauss_y)**2) / sum(data.reshape(201,201)))

initial_guess = (np.max(data), mean_gauss_x, mean_gauss_y, sigma_gauss_x, sigma_gauss_y,0,10)
```

Then

```
print(inital_guess)
```

yields

```
(13.0, array([...]), array([...]), array([...]), array([...]), 0, 10)
```

Notice that some of the values in `initial_guess` are arrays. The `optimize.curve_fit` function expects `initial_guess` to be a tuple of scalars. This is the source of the problem.

---

The error message

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

often arises when an array-like is supplied when a scalar value is expected. It is a hint that the source of the problem may have to do with an array having the wrong number of dimensions. For example, it might arise if you pass a 1D array to a function that expects a scalar.

---

Let's look at this piece of code taken from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566379/fitting-a-2d-gaussian-function-using-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-valueerror-and-m):

```
x = np.linspace(0, 200, 201)
y = np.linspace(0, 200, 201)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

`x` and `y` are 1D arrays, while `X` and `Y` are 2D arrays. (I've capitalized all 2D arrays to help distinguish them from 1D arrays).

Now notice that Python `sum` and NumPy's `sum` method behave differently when applied to 2D arrays:

```
In [146]: sum(X)
Out[146]: 
array([    0.,   201.,   402.,   603.,   804.,  1005.,  1206.,  1407.,
        1608.,  1809.,  2010.,  2211.,  2412.,  2613.,  2814.,  3015.,
        ...
       38592., 38793., 38994., 39195., 39396., 39597., 39798., 39999.,
       40200.])

In [147]: X.sum()
Out[147]: 4040100.0
```

The Python `sum` function is equivalent to

```
total = 0
for item in X:
    total += item
```

Since `X` is a 2D array, the loop `for item in X` is iterating over the *rows of X*. Each `item` is therefore a 1D array representing a row of `X`. Thus, `total` ends up being a 1D array.

In contrast, `X.sum()` sums all the elements in `X` and returns a scalar.

Since `initial_guess` should be a tuple of scalars, 
everywhere you use `sum` you should instead use the NumPy `sum` method. For example, replace

```
mean_gauss_x = sum(x * data) / sum(data)
```

with

```
mean_gauss_x = (X * DATA).sum() / (DATA.sum())
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define model function and pass independant variables x and y as a list
def twoD_Gaussian(data, amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, offset):
    X, Y = data
    xo = float(xo)
    yo = float(yo)
    a = (np.cos(theta) ** 2) / (2 * sigma_x ** 2) + (np.sin(theta) ** 2) / (
        2 * sigma_y ** 2
    )
    b = -(np.sin(2 * theta)) / (4 * sigma_x ** 2) + (np.sin(2 * theta)) / (
        4 * sigma_y ** 2
    )
    c = (np.sin(theta) ** 2) / (2 * sigma_x ** 2) + (np.cos(theta) ** 2) / (
        2 * sigma_y ** 2
    )
    g = offset + amplitude * np.exp(
        -(a * ((X - xo) ** 2) + 2 * b * (X - xo) * (Y - yo) + c * ((Y - yo) ** 2))
    )
    return g.ravel()


# Create x and y indices
x = np.linspace(0, 200, 201)
y = np.linspace(0, 200, 201)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# create data
data = twoD_Gaussian((X, Y), 3, 100, 100, 20, 40, 0, 10)
data_noisy = data + 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=data.shape)
DATA = data.reshape(201, 201)


# add some noise to the data and try to fit the data generated beforehand
mean_gauss_x = (X * DATA).sum() / (DATA.sum())
sigma_gauss_x = np.sqrt((DATA * (X - mean_gauss_x) ** 2).sum() / (DATA.sum()))

mean_gauss_y = (Y * DATA).sum() / (DATA.sum())
sigma_gauss_y = np.sqrt((DATA * (Y - mean_gauss_y) ** 2).sum() / (DATA.sum()))


initial_guess = (
    np.max(data),
    mean_gauss_x,
    mean_gauss_y,
    sigma_gauss_x,
    sigma_gauss_y,
    0,
    10,
)
print(initial_guess)
# (13.0, 100.00000000000001, 100.00000000000001, 57.106515650488404, 57.43620227324201, 0, 10)
# initial_guess = (3,100,100,20,40,0,10)

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, (X, Y), data_noisy, p0=initial_guess)

data_fitted = twoD_Gaussian((X, Y), *popt)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(
    data_noisy.reshape(201, 201),
    cmap=plt.cm.jet,
    origin="bottom",
    extent=(X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max()),
)
ax.contour(X, Y, data_fitted.reshape(201, 201), 8, colors="w")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for the answer, the code seems to work! I'll keep in mind the difference between sum() and np.sum()