# Apply Gaussian profile on 2D image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gaussian

I need to know how to apply Gaussian function on this image as 1D Gaussian fit or 2D Gaussian fit using MATLAB.

[image: Image of (what looks like) a fluorescent bead]

Comment: What is “apply Gaussian function”? Do you mean “fit Gaussian function”? Or do you want to filter the image with a Gaussian kernel? Something else?

Comment: Hi Cris,

I mean the fit Gaussian function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Gero Nootz's Fit 2D Gaussian Function to Data](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37087).
It uses a simple model with an example how to use MATLAB's optimizers to get the model parameters.

You may also have a look at [Fitting a 2D Gaussian function using scipy.optimize.curve_fit - ValueError and minpack.error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566379/fitting-a-2d-gaussian-function-using-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-valueerror-and-m).

Comment: Thanks Eric. How does this model function handle pixels? Is the fitting work only on the pixels that cross the line or the summing of the pixels on the entire x and y axis?

Comment: For 2D it means it evaluates the best fit taking advantage of all pixels.